# How to create webService using NetBeans IDE?

Tags: java

I am very much new to java.I need to create simple web service using NetBeans IDE. How to create it?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what kind of Web Service it is and what version of Netbeans you use. You can follow the Netbeans (6.9) documentation here http://netbeans.org/features/web/web-services.html